# How to get innerHTML of td in dynamically populated table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a table and populated values from an array, so I have 5x5 table, where each `td` will be filled with a word. The word come from array `memo` and all the code below works fine.

```
var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("results")
var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

table.border = '1'
table.appendChild(tableBody);

//TABLE ROWS
for (i = 0; i < this.memo.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < this.memo[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.onclick = function () {
            check();
        }
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.memo[i][j]));
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}  
myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

I have one question : I would like to click on the cell and get the word, which belongs to the cell. 
For this purpose I tried `onclick` as I created `td` element

```
   td.onclick = function () {
            check();
        }
```

The function check should print the innerHTML of the cell, which was clicked

```
function check() {
    var a = td.innerHTML;
    console.log(a);
}
```

But it gives me always wrong text - the last one in the array, which was populated.
How could I solve it?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why it's always giving you the first element: after the `for (j = 0; ...` loop is finished, the variable `td` will hold the value of the last element in the list. Then, when `check` is called, it accesses that same `td` variable pointing to the last element.

To solve this, you can add an argument to the function to accept a specific element and log that.

```
td.onclick = function () {
  check(td);
};

// later...
function check(element) {
  var html = element.innerHTML;
  console.log(html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you too! I cannot mark as right answer two answers, but it helped me too, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You always get the last `td` in the array because the last value that was set to `td` was of the last cell. You need to add the a parameter, say `event`, to `onclick`'s callback function, and then your clicked element will be referenced in `event.target`. Then you would be able to get it's innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the innerHTML in the click itself - please see working example below, with some mock data for memo.

```js
var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("results")
var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')
var memo = [
['joe', 'tom', 'pete'],
['sara','lily', 'julia'],
['cody','timmy', 'john']
]

table.border = '1'
table.appendChild(tableBody);

//TABLE ROWS
for (i = 0; i < this.memo.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < this.memo[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.onclick = function () {
            check(this.innerHTML);
        }
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.memo[i][j]));
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}  
myTableDiv.appendChild(table);

function check(a) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try..

```
td.onclick = function () {
    check();
}
```

to

```js
td.onclick = function (evt) {
    var html = evt.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(html);
    check(html);  //to do something..
}
```